# Secure access to a file

Tags: file-management, file-permissions

In an android phone, generally we use App Locker or other applications for securing applications.

Like App Locker, how to restrict media files (images and video)? I don’t want to hide them.

I would like to restrict media files with pattern/ password/ PIN lock.

And once a media file restricted, it must be restricted irrespective of any file explorer/ media player/ image viewer.

Please let me know some better apps or other ways for restricting media file access so that it can’t be accessed by any other ways.

Regards
GNS

Comment: Use a container, you'll have different environments for private use and normal use. What phone are you using? Samsung has MyKnox.

Comment: I am using iBall BraceX1 Tablet. Its android 4.4.2 with root access.